# NuGet shows already updated packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a pretty big solution (currently 55 projects) with nearly all of them having NuGet packages installed into them. Every one of them works perfectly with NuGet if I use the **Project-based** "Manage NuGet Packages" dialog.

Unfortunately, every time I use the **Solution-based** "Manage NuGet Packages", it displays me a multitude of updatable packages under Updates, even though all of them are already installed in the corresponding projects.

This is the case for months now (maybe upwards of a year) and this problem survived several NuGet updates. Honestly, I don't really have an idea where this could be coming from (didn't see anything obviously wrong with all of the NuGet files like packages.config etc).

What could be reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past. For me cleaning the content of the packages folders and erasing the NuGet package cache worked.